# Route Prefix can be overridden

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have an base controller which perform few post and get on offers, below i gave an sample structure of get

```
[AxAuthorization(Resource = "Offers")]
[RoutePrefix("api/offer/v2/offers")]
public class OffersV2Controller : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}", Name = "OffersGetById")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetById([FromUri(Name = "id")]string OfferId)
    {
             ----
             -----
      }
}
```

we are calling this get method by  api/offer/v2/offers/id , but some other consumer who are using our services, they like to call as api/v2/offers/id, is there any way we can override it ? the above code is kind of code generated by product which we does't want to modify the route prefix.

Comment: i don't want to modify this class file, instead can i write some override method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Route("api/v2/offer/test")]
[Route("api/offer/v2/test")]
```

OR

> ```
>      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
>         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
>             name: "route1",
>             routeTemplate: "test/v2/Values",
>             defaults: new { controller = "Values", action = "Get" });
> ```

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "route2",
            routeTemplate: "v2/test/Values",
            defaults: new { controller = "Values", action = "Get" });


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

in the webapiConfig.cs

Comment: I don't want to add multiple route, I like to understand more about global.asax.cs  do you mean i need to add, config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "Offer",
               routeTemplate: "Offers"
           );